# Sax parsing with localname more than one appearance

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

Is there a clever way to parse a tag found in two different areas?

```
@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {    
if (localName.equals("item")) {
       this.in_item = true;
    }
}
```

example:

```
<xml>
   <item>
      <test1 />
      <item />
      <test2 />
   </item>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a [`Stack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) of previously seen nodes, and manage our node accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When I had the above case I just set a Boolean var found1item to true and when finding the next item I check for this item and set found1item to false again. If you have deeper nesting it might be hard to implement, but if it is only nested once it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

take parent nodes and child nodes, 1st iterate the loop with parent node, then iterate the loop with child nodes.

Comment: You are going to end up getting your account and all your posts deleted if you keep spamming your blog address in your posts like this. I've warned you already.